# Can I reformat a Windows PC hard drive and install the Ubuntu Operating System

Tags: windows, downloads, burning

My daughter gave me her old PC, and I reformatted the hard drive with my own XP System Disk.  However, if I don’t activate the license, which I can’t, it will self-destruct within 30 days.

1. If I download the Ubuntu software, can I burn it on a CD and re-format the hard drive, and also install the Ubuntu operating system on the hard drive?
2. Will that  CD have accessory software applications included, e.g. a word processor, a spreadsheet, a video player, video editor, photo application, etc., as indicated on your website?
3. If I can't get Internet access on the Ubuntu PC would I be able to download some freebie applications such as Irfanview and OpenOffice on my other (Windows) PC, and transfer the download files to the Ubuntu machine, and install them?

Answer (score 2):

> If I download the Ubuntu software, can I burn it on a CD and re-format the hard drive, and also install the Ubuntu operating system on the hard drive?

Yes, Actually Ubuntu is more than a software, It is an Operating System.

> Will that CD have accessory software applications included, e.g. a word processor, a spreadsheet, a video player, video editor, photo application, etc., as indicated on your website?

Yes, it includes

- Word processor = LibreOffice writer
- Spreadsheet = LibreOffice Calc
- Video player = Totem
- Video editor = No (Earlier versions of Ubuntu had pitivi video editor, but 12.04 has none) You can of course download the video editor after installing Ubuntu

> If I can't get Internet access on the Ubuntu PC would I be able to download some freebie applications such as Irfanview and OpenOffice on my other (Windows) PC, and transfer the download files to the Ubuntu machine, and install them?

Not exactly, You may have assumed that, Windows programs and Ubuntu programs are similar. Actually it isn't. You can't expect Windows program to run on Ubuntu just like you run it in Windows. Such as Irfanview. But of course, Some of the Windows program can be run using [WINE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)), but it is not like Ubuntu native programs.

See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) to know How Ubuntu differs from a Windows PC.

See this question to have an alternative to Irfanview: [Ubuntu replacement for IrfanView](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44864/ubuntu-replacement-for-irfanview)

For OpenOffice, you have LibreOffice pre-installed which is very much compatible with Microsoft Office and OpenOffice.

Comment: In fact, Libreoffice is almost exactly OpenOffice to the naked eye.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes - [How to burn a CD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows)
2. Yes - [Pre-installed applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Applications). And lots more available to install from the repositories, most of the applications are free.
3. Technically yes, but it's much easier with having internet access on the Ubuntu machine. You don't really need to do anything to install OpenOffice or an image viewer, they come pre-installed.

Answer (score -2):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes. Look into downloading a .deb file. A deb file is like a windows .exe file used for downloading programs. http://txt.binnyva.com/2009/03/download-deb-files-using-apt-get/ and then install with `dpgk -i myfile.deb`.