# How to get access to USB-storage from an application installed as Snap?

Tags: permissions, 18.04, snap, usb-drive

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed.

I inserted USB-flash to my laptop. It was automounted to */media/username/DISKLABEL* and opened in Nautilus. I can read and write objects to it.

How can I access it from the application, which is installed as Snap?

I tried snaps of the following applications such as `gedit`, `arduino-mhall119`, `organize-my-files`. All them show me errors if I navigate to */media* folder:

[image: trying to access /media]

[image: trying to access /media]

> **Could not read the contents of Media**
>
> Error opening the directory of '/media': permission denied

Output of active Snap [interfaces](https://docs.snapcraft.io/reference/interfaces) is below:

```
$ snap interfaces  | grep -v ".*-$"
Slot                             Plug
:browser-support                 organize-my-files
:core-support                    core:core-support-plug
:cups-control                    gedit
:desktop                         gedit,organize-my-files
:desktop-legacy                  gedit,organize-my-files
:gsettings                       gedit,organize-my-files
:home                            arduino-mhall119,gedit,organize-my-files
:network                         arduino-mhall119,gedit,organize-my-files,pulsemixer
:opengl                          organize-my-files
:pulseaudio                      organize-my-files,pulsemixer
:unity7                          arduino-mhall119,gedit,organize-my-files
:wayland                         gedit
:x11                             arduino-mhall119,organize-my-files,pulsemixer
gnome-3-26-1604:gnome-3-26-1604  gedit
gtk-common-themes:gtk3-themes    gedit
gtk-common-themes:icon-themes    gedit
gtk-common-themes:sound-themes   gedit
-                                arduino-mhall119:serial-port
-                                gedit:avahi-observe
-                                gedit:mount-observe
```

Updates:

- connecting *mount-observe* to Gedit with `snap connect gedit:mount-observe` does not help.
- it seems that we need special Snap with support of [`removable-media`](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/wiki/Interfaces#removable-media) interface.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So we need special prepared Snap with support of `removable-media` connector/interface/plugin.

Below is a list of Snap with *removable-media* plug described in YAML-manifest :

- **vlc** - [VLC](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/extras/package/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L27)
- **firefox** - [Firefox](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/taskcluster/docker/firefox-snap/snapcraft.yaml.in#28)
- **gimp** - [GIMP](https://github.com/snapcrafters/gimp/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L34)
- **mdl** - [Markdown lint tool](https://github.com/snapcrafters/mdl/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L14)
- **offlineimap** - [OfflineIMAP](https://github.com/snapcrafters/offlineimap/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L18)
- **magic-wormhole** - [Magic Worm Hole](https://github.com/snapcrafters/magic-wormhole/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L22)
- **mattermost-desktop** - [Mattermost](https://github.com/snapcrafters/mattermost-desktop/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L63)
- **storjshare-gui** - [Storj](https://github.com/snapcrafters/storjshare-gui/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L76)
- **opentoonz** - [OpenToonz](https://github.com/snapcrafters/opentoonz/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L24)
- **opentoonz-morevna** - [**OpenToonz** - Morevna Edition](https://github.com/snapcrafters/opentoonz-morevna/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L24)
- **obs-studio** - [OBS Studio](https://github.com/snapcrafters/obs-studio/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L27)
- **steamforwindows** - [Steam for Windows under Wine](https://github.com/snapcrafters/steamforwindows/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L34)
- **chromium**
- **zotero-snap** - [Zotero](https://github.com/extraymond/zotero-snap/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L37)
- **libreoffice** - [libreoffice-snap](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+git/libreoffice-snap/tree/snap/snapcraft.yaml#n330)
- **Joplin Desktop** - [joplin-desktop](https://github.com/MrCarroll/joplin-desktop-snap/blob/cf0abca3984a164fffd6108bb3eb7c581aa7566d/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L66)

One can find other Snaps released by SnapCrafters with the following [GitHub search link](https://github.com/search?l=YAML&q=org%3Asnapcrafters+removable-media&type=Code).

---

So if the application does not have auto-connect of `removable-media` we need to connect it manually with:

```
snap connect some-snap-name:removable-media
```

But not all applications have this plug/interface in YAML-manifest.

---

It is hard to find packages by supported plugs - so I created [issue "Add ability for parametric Snap search with filters (plugs, such as `removable-media` and so on)" about snapcraft.io site](https://github.com/canonical-websites/snapcraft.io/issues/642).

The bug about `snap` command named ["`snap` should provide functionality to find packages with needed plug or connector" was filed to launchpad as bug 1776938](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1776938).

Comment: The correct command is: `snap connect some-snap-name:removable-media`

Comment: @ZygmuntKrynicki of course. Thank you, I fixed this silly typo.

Comment: The bug which is cited in the last two paragraphs is truly annoying, but a simple workaround for it if the snap package is already installed is `snap interfaces some-snap-name`

Comment: @karel, right. Thank you! I have this command already in question. The main problem is to determine plugs of non-installed Snap.

Comment: The bug which is cited in the last two paragraphs is truly annoying, but a simple workaround for it if the snap package is already installed is `snap connections some-snap-name` This is an update of my previous comment.

Comment: This was causing `ffmpeg` to give me `Permission Denied` errors, which was really mind-boggling. Wasted like an hour on this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: So the snap creator must have made provision in the yaml and only then can we use `snap connect some-snap-name:removable-media`?

Comment: @DKBose look like that, otherwise the `snap connect ...` will not work.

Answer (score 18):

The Ubuntu Software program will now show a Permissions button on the page of each Snap program you have installed.

[image: the Krita page of Ubuntu Software program showing the buttons under the title - Launch, Remove, and Permissions]

Click on Permissions, and a pop-up window gives you the option 'Read/write files on removable storage devices', with a button to the right that you click to turn this on.

[image]

You need to activate each program one by one this way, but there is nothing special to remember, other than that the button exists.

Comment: Please add screenshot of "Click on Permissions, and a pop-up window" to the answer.

Comment: @N0rbert Done...

Comment: This also works for accessing mounted NTFS drives from Snap apps, thank you.

Comment: How to allow an arbitrary path, such as `/data/photos`?

Comment: I have no option for "removable storage devices", in Ubuntu v20.04, snap v2.58.2, for "Teams-insiders"

Answer (score 4):

To access USB storage from a snap, it needs a *connection* to `removable-media`. Some snaps are automatically connected to it. If not, you can manually connect it using the following command:

```
snap connect snap-name:removable-media
```

Sometimes, this command fails with the following message:

```
error: snap "snap-name" has no plug named "removable-media"
```

This means the publisher of the package has not indicated that the application *can* use removable media. In this case, you should contact the publisher and ask them to add the [`removable-media` interface](https://snapcraft.io/docs/removable-media-interface) to the plugs of the Snap.

Most Snaps show how to contact the publisher; run `snap info snap-name` and look at the `contact` field for an email address or a URL.

### Automatically connecting `removable-media`

It is possible for publishers to request that their Snap is automatically connected to the `removable-media` interface. This is allowed for applications that fall into the following categories.

- **Major browsers** such as Brave, Firefox and Chromium.
- **Media editors** such as photo editors like gimp, video editors like OpenToonz or audio editors like Audacity.
- **Media players/viewers** such as video players like VLC media player or image viewing programs.
- **Media recorders** such as a screencast program, a webcam program, OBS Studio or a podcast recording application.

If an application falls into one of these categories and `removable-media` is not automatically connected to the application, please contact the publisher and ask them to [request an auto-connection](https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management#heading--auto-connections) to `removable-media`.

Comment: as a developer without too much understanding of the situation, why is there so much guarding about access to removable media? i am having trouble confguring this properly, and now i'm seeing from this post, my app won't even get access to it unless I request auto-connection, which seems like a weird process to go through

Comment: @ColinD Because removable media is one of the primary methods for spreading malware, and because removable media often contains sensitive data like keys in non-standard directories.

Comment: Note that if you use the XDG desktop portal for file access, you don't need the auto connections. This portal asks the user if the app is allowed to open certain files.

Answer (score 3):

The interface which needs to be connected is `removable-media`.

*Can access files from removable media in /media and /run/media. This can be used to give an app access to mounted USB sticks and external hard drives on a desktop.*

The `mount-observe` interface only lets you view what is mounted, not access mounts:

*Can query system mount information. This is restricted because it gives privileged read access to mount arguments and should only be used with trusted apps.*

Neither of these two interfaces will auto-connect. From https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/wiki/Interfaces#removable-media

Comment: I don't know. It seems obs-studio does, but I only found it due to it mentioning the interface in the description of the app for how to access external storage. I don't know how to query the store for specific interfaces in snaps. If a specific snap doesn't support the interface, it will presumably need to be rebuilt to support it.

Answer (score 2):

The snap app needs to have `removable-media` plug enabled in order to access USB storage and other drives. You can do this through **Part 1** below.

If you are unlucky enough to need a snap that does not have `removable-media` support, then you can try adding it as per the instructions below.

I had to do this for the *freeplane* (mind-mapping app) snap and a similar process should work for other snaps as well. I will use *freeplane* in the instructions below - please replace it with the equivalent for your snap app.

**Part 1: Check for removable-media support**

1. Search for the exact installed snap app name using `snap list | grep freeplane`. This showed the snap name is `freeplane-mindmapping` with version number [1.9.7].
2. Try connecting to removable media using `sudo snap connect freeplane-mindmapping:removable-media`. If you do not get any error messages, then removable-media is enabled and **STOP HERE: your work is done!**
3. If you get the error message `error: snap "freeplane-mindmapping" has no plug named "removable-media"`, then emovable-media plug is not enabled in that snap app.
4. Check to see which connections are enabled using `snap connections freeplane-mindmapping`, which should result is something like:
   [image: enabled snap connections list]

Note that the above output does not show the `removable-media` interface, but it does show a list of other interfaces started with `cups-control` and ending with `x11`. We will be adding `removable-media` after `x11` in the .yaml configuration file for this snap app.

**Part 2: Unsquash the snap file**

[As per Bernard Wei' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1046677/553502), snap files are mounted as read-only so to modify them, you will need to unsquash it, modify the files and then re-make the squashfs file.

1. Type `mount |grep freeplane` to find the snap filepath (`/var/lib/snapd/snaps/freeplane-mindmapping_29.snap`) and mount point (`/snap/freeplane-mindmapping/29`). Keep a note of both the filepath and the mount point as these will be needed later.
   [image]
2. Unmount this snap using `sudo umount /snap/freeplane-mindmapping/29`. Typing `snap list | grep freeplane` will now show the snap as 'broken'.
   [image]
3. Unsquash snap file by typing `sudo unsquashfs /var/lib/snapd/snaps/freeplane-mindmapping_29.snap`. The snap file will be extracted to  `~/squashfs-root/`.
4. Using Nautilus, go to the `~/squashfs-root/meta` (eg using Ctrl-L).
5. Right click and `Edit as Administrator` the file `snap.yaml`.
6. Scroll down to the section called `plugs` and enter in `removable-media` after `x11`:
   [image]
7. Save and close the gedit/editor

**Part 3: Reinsert the modified snap file**

1. Remake the snap file using `sudo mksquashfs squashfs-root freeplane-mindmapping_29.snap`. The modified snap file will be created in the Home folder.
2. Overwrite the original snap file with the modified snap using `sudo cp freeplane-mindmapping_29.snap /var/lib/snapd/snaps/freeplane-mindmapping_29.snap`.
3. Mount the modified snap to the original mount location using `sudo mount -t squashfs -o ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide /var/lib/snapd/snaps/freeplane-mindmapping_29.snap /snap/freeplane-mindmapping/29`.
4. If it worked, `snap list | grep freeplane` will no longer show the snap as "broken".
   [image]
5. If `snap connections freeplane-mindmapping` does not show `removable-media`, then reboot.
6. Now `snap connections freeplane-mindmapping` should show `removable-media`.
   [image]
7. Enable removable-media using `snap connect freeplane-mindmapping:removable-media`.
   **You should now have access to removable media!**
8. [Optional] Delete the `squashfs-root` folder using `sudo rm -r ~/squashfs-root`.
9. [Optional] For easy access, you can make a symbolic link to your removable media using `ln -s /path/to/folder ~/snap/freeplane-mindmapping/29/`.

Good luck!