# Cannot edit system file /snap/phpstorm... even with root account in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions, 18.04, filesystem, editing

I installed a snap package in Ubuntu 18.04 package and I want to edit one of its files using root account. First I switched to root with `su`, but then when I opened file in nano it tells me:

```
 [ File '/snap/phpstorm/36/bin/phpstorm64.vmoptions' is unwritable ]
```

Then I tried this:

```
root@elahe-VPCEA31FX:/home/elahe# sudoedit  /snap/phpstorm/36/bin/phpstorm64.vmoptions
```

after above command the file opened in nano, but after making changes and saving with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after exiting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> I got this message:

```
sudoedit: unable to write to /snap/phpstorm/36/bin/phpstorm64.vmoptions: Read-only file system
sudoedit: contents of edit session left in /var/tmp/phpstorm64XXRCQzZi.vmoptions
```

I even tried to change the permissions of the file with this command:

```
root@elahe-VPCEA31FX:/home/elahe# chmod 755  /snap/phpstorm/36/bin/phpstorm64.vmoptions
```

and got this:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/snap/phpstorm/36/bin/phpstorm64.vmoptions': Read-only file system
```

It is really amazing that the root user cannot edit a file! Is this a bug?

Comment: Not even root can modify a read-only file system (which is what `/snap` is).

Comment: Do you mean that there a no way to edit a system file?!

Answer (score 14):

The snap files are mounted as read-only (ro), and you can check this by using the mount command.

```
mount |grep snap
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_158.snap on /snap/vlc/158 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4486.snap on /snap/core/4486 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4571.snap on /snap/core/4571 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_365.snap on /snap/vlc/365 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_190.snap on /snap/vlc/190 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4650.snap on /snap/core/4650 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
```

To modify files in squashfs, you need to unsquash it, modify the files and then re-make the squashfs file. E.g., if I want to modify files in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_365.snap`

```
sudo umount /snap/vlc/365
sudo unsquashfs /var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_365.snap
```

Modify anything you want in `squashfs-root` (it's where all the files are unpacked into), and then repack it.

```
sudo mksquashfs squashfs-root vlc_365.snap
```

Copy it back to its original location and re-mount it.

```
sudo cp vlc_365.snap /var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_365.snap
sudo mount -t squashfs -o ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide /var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_365.snap /snap/vlc/365
```

Comment: Great solution. Saved my time.

Comment: I corrupted my partition while doing this :|  `internal error, please report: running "<app>" failed: open /snap/<app>/40/meta/snap.yaml: input/output error`

Comment: What about remounting with rw? "sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point". Does it work with squashfs?