# Error open repository from Apache server using GitKraken on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions, apache2

I'm trying to open an Apache project repository from GitKraken but I am getting error with permissions because I can't access the `/var` folder.

[image: GitKraken permission error]

My folder has this route: `var/www/html/Catalogo`. Inside the folder named 'Catalogo' I have my Git repository.

I found this Stack Overflow post having my same problem but the error was not solved: [link to Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378270/ubuntu-gitkraken-unable-to-access-var). There is an comment suggesting to make a post here, but I can't find that post.

Any help is appreciated.

**[EDIT]**

I also show the output ot `snap list` command

[image: snap list output]

Comment: How did you install GitKraken?

Comment: From the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: As I may see it is not [deb-packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=GitKraken). Please add output of `snap list` to the question.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the described behaviour is that snap applications are installed by default with confined permissions. This is a deliberate choice and you can read more on the subject here:

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/advanced-snap-usage#3
4. Handling interfaces and permissions in your snaps

The plugin removable-media seems to be declared in:
https://github.com/mmtrt/gitkraken/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml

The snap connect for this plugin did not work for me either. (I am unsure the above was the correct git repository for this snap, as the author mentions not maintaining it any longer as it now released by Axosoft.)

Thus leaves you with few options:
(1) actively do something to make it work by contributing to the code (if possible)
(2) **trust the application and install it with "devmode" permissions**
(3) wait utill `snap connect gitkraken:removable-media` starts working

In case you wish to proceed with option (2) and install the application with devmode permissions (you should know that you grant access to the app to anything your user would have access to):

```
sudo snap remove gitkraken
sudo snap install --devmode gitkraken
```

to verify if the installation happened as intended you can check for "devmode" by running the command "**snap list**" (see how this are supposed to have changed, you may have more snaps listed here, I have included only the one you should check)

```
snap list

Name               Version        Rev   Tracking  Publisher         Notes
gitkraken          4.1.1          134   stable    gitkraken✓        -
```

targeted outcome

```
Name               Version        Rev   Tracking  Publisher         Notes
gitkraken          4.1.1          134   stable    gitkraken✓        devmode
```

Cheers,
Happy Coding!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** *Excellent* first answer!  *Keep up the good work!*  **+1 to your answer means +10 to your rep!**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that GitKraken Snap do not have access to internal storage, but it has access to home folder.

Connecting `removable-media` with `snap connect gitkraken:removable-media` does not help.

Consider one of the following:

- move your repository to home folder.
- remove GitKraken with `snap remove gitkraken` and install version from official site.

For other similar issues see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1034030/66509).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution for this issue on the [snapcraft.io](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/create-an-interface-to-allow-snap-app-access-var-www-directory/5238) forum.

You can mount your `var/www/html/Catalogo` directory to a new folder inside your home directory, and you can open that from Gitkraken.

```
mkdir $HOME/www/Catalogo
sudo mount -obind /var/www/html/Catalogo $HOME/www/Catalogo
```