# LibreOffice 6.1 won't open files over cifs network share on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, libreoffice, cifs

I have some file stored on a Network share which I have mounted as as a drive on my ubuntu desktop.

In LibreOffice 6.0, it would open the files, but keep me in read-only (pretty sure due to a network permission which I have not fixed).

In LibreOffice 6.1, it won't even open the file. It just says 'access to {filename} is denied'

However, If I copy and paste the file to my desktop, it opens fine.

Any ideas?

Information Ask Requsted:

from the `mount` command, this is the locate of the mount i'm accessing:

```
//data-server.myserver.lan/Server on /home/david/Server type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=default,cache=strict,username=My Name,domain=mydomain,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=10.0.0.6,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,noperm,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,_netdev)
```

from `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   2.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/222
loop1    7:1    0 174.2M  1 loop /snap/gitkraken/90
loop2    7:2    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/45
loop3    7:3    0  87.9M  1 loop /snap/core/5328
loop4    7:4    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/117
loop5    7:5    0 143.9M  1 loop /snap/slack/7
loop6    7:6    0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop7    7:7    0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/199
loop8    7:8    0    87M  1 loop /snap/core/5145
loop9    7:9    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop10   7:10   0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop11   7:11   0   140M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
loop12   7:12   0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop13   7:13   0  93.5M  1 loop /snap/slack/6
loop14   7:14   0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/101
loop15   7:15   0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop16   7:16   0 477.9M  1 loop /snap/libreoffice/80
loop17   7:17   0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
loop18   7:18   0  34.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop19   7:19   0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/40
loop20   7:20   0 174.2M  1 loop /snap/gitkraken/94
loop21   7:21   0 174.2M  1 loop /snap/gitkraken/87
loop22   7:22   0 139.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
loop23   7:23   0 141.5M  1 loop /snap/slack/8
loop24   7:24   0 140.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop25   7:25   0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/34
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 238.5G  0 part /
```

And `ls -l [the file]`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 36864 Sep 11 10:47 '/home/david/Server/SetUp/Docs/IT.docx'
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Looks like a permissions problem. Care to share a bit more info on your setup? Can you edit your question and post the output of `mount`, `lsblk`, maybe an `ls -l [path of the file you're trying to open]`?

Comment: @MrShunz I've added the requested information.

Comment: cifs means you want to use NFS mount and not Samba, right? NFS is tricky and has a big issue: If the user (UID) is not identical for server and client you get the most weird results - or no access. My suggestion: Try to access the same files with SMB and see if it works. I had the same issue in a small company - we switched to SMB for production and NFS as fall back (NFS devastates the file owner and access rights on file level). MOREOVER you will experience undocumented changes in the mount syntax from Ubuntu version to version. You can not give UMASK! I can give you a working mount phrase.

Comment: For me it looks as possible duplicate of [How to get access to USB-storage from the application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap) . It is about Snap restrictions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE I can confirm your issue using LibreOffice 6.1 installed from snap:

```
$ snap list libreoffice
Name         Version  Rev  Tracking  Publisher   Notes
libreoffice  6.1.0.3  80   stable    canonical✓  -
```

I have mounted two shares from Caja:

- SMB/CIFS (on `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.111.111,share=public`)
- SFTP/SSHFS (on `/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=192.168.111.111/home/user/Public`).

When I try to open ODS or ODT file from them with LibreOffice I get almost similar error messages from LibreOffice:

> [image: SMB/CIFS]
>   [image: SSHFS/SFTP]

I tried to solve the problem by connecting interfaces to the Snap

```
snap connect libreoffice:removable-media
snap connect libreoffice:network
snap connect libreoffice:network-bind
```

with no luck.

So we have discovered new problem of Snap applications. We already have problem with [external media](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap).
As we need to use network storage we will remove this pretty new Snap packages of LibO with

```
snap remove libreoffice
```

and install normal deb-based version instead:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

and open network files in normal read and write mode.

Comment: I removed libreoffice via the snap command and apt-get installed it instead. Now it opens it. THANKS! How can I get these to show up in the list with the rest of my apps?

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I get these to show up in the list with the rest of my apps?"? Do you mean desktop intergration?

Comment: Whne I click on 'Show Applications', I get icons for all my apps/programs (i'm running on desktop). Libreoffice doesn't show with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Research: I'm seeing the same issue on Debian 10 with the Mate desktop. I have /etc/fstab configured to mount the (NAS) Cifs at boot time, but the MATE desktop file manager seems to mount it a second time. If I navigate to a file on the cifs starting from the File Manager "filesystem" shortcut, it finds the boot-time mount point, and LibreOffice opens the file with no issues. However, if I browse to the same file starting from the File Manager "Network" shortcut, it finds MATE's alternate mount point, and LibreOffice simply doesn't open it - no error, no file, no joy in Mudville.

I brought up two File Manager windows, navigated to the same file, and compared the file permissions. From the "Filesystem" shortcut, the File Manager shows owner as "pmartz (Paul Martz)" but from "Network" owner shows as just "pmartz". The MATE file manager doesn't have an option to show the actual user/group IDs (1000/1000 in my case).

So I can work around the problem by always using the "Filesystem" shortcut as the start of my navigation, but I'd like to find a way for MATE's second mount point to mount the cifs with the my user/group ID.

Comment: My testing:
/ Debian 12 MATE (fresh install): has the problem
/ Debian 12 Cinnamon (fresh install): Works okay
/ Ubuntu 22.04 MATE: Works okay

Comment: All 3 of my test systems had the libreoffice-gtk3 pkg installed. The Ubuntu/MATE server also had libreoffice-gnome installed -- but Debian/MATE didn't. I installed that pkg and it fixed the problem.