# could not open remote file with libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, remote-access, sftp

I can't  open any remote file with libreoffice. When to open files on remote folders(mounted by `sftp`), a error `General input/output error while accessing (path of my file)/summary_counts.csv` showed by libreoffice. But I can open the file with any other editors like sublime. 
What happened to libreoffice?

Comment: Do you have the package `libreoffice-gnome` installed?

Comment: yes: `libreoffice-gnome is already the newest version (1:6.2.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1).`

Comment: Did you install the snap package for libreoffice? [This user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074248/libreoffice-6-1-wont-open-files-over-cifs-network-share-on-ubuntu) had a similar problem.

Comment: If not, you could `mount` the remote folder as a `sshfs` share. That seems to help.

Comment: it works when mounted by `sshfs`. Thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and resolved it in a similar way: use cifs to mount the drive locally. (You need to install the cifs-utils for this to work.)

I would like to add that I am using Ubuntu 18.04 minimal.  I have tried both the snap version of LO and the (old) .deb version (6.x) and neither loaded the remote file.  Furthermore the local mount only works (for me) if I force SMB v.1. Otherwise it's read only (a problem I had last  year as well.)

Also I notice that the Ubuntu full installation of Ubuntu 19 (dingo) works fine, but the minimal install of 19 (dingo) has the same problem.

My assumption here is that the minimal installs are lacking something.

L.