# How to get snap installed SimpleScreenRecorder to save output file to removable media?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, snap

I **installed SimpleScreenRecorder** with command:

```
$ sudo snap install simplescreenrecorder
```

I then tried to **configure** a record session so that the **output would be saved on a USB drive**, but as soon as I try and access the `/media` folder for the `Save As` path, I get the following **error**:
[image]

Having experienced the same issue with GIMP in an earlier post, I tried the following command (which worked for GIMP) to solve the problem:

```
$ sudo snap connect simplescreenrecorder:removable-media
```

However, that resulted in the following error message:

```
error: snap "simplescreenrecorder" has no plug named "removable-media"
```

**Is it possible to have SimpleScreenRecorder output to removable media, or is there a technical barrier preventing this?**

**Update:**
I find that SimpleScreenRecorder is now **available to install from apt** directly. So I removed the snap version:

```
sudo snap remove simplescreenrecorder
```

Then installed from apt:

```
sudo apt install simplescreenrecorder
```

The trust and permissions that come with being a core apt package means the application has access to removable media without further configuration.

Comment: +1 to using the repo version when available. It's been available in the repos since 17.10 and [via ppa](https://launchpad.net/~maarten-baert/+archive/ubuntu/simplescreenrecorder).

Answer (score 1):

Currently we have "good" and "bad" snaps:

- "Bad" snaps do not have access to removable-media.
- "Good" snaps have access to removable-media. I created small list of them in [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034065/66509).

---

In your particular case (as you already wrote):

```
snap connect simplescreenrecorder:removable-media
```

will return

> ```
> error: snap "simplescreenrecorder" has no plug named "removable-media"`.
> ```

So it can't access removable media by design.

But you have other option - remove this nice snap with

```
snap remove simplescreenrecorder
```

and install version from APT (as it is available in [the *universe* repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=simplescreenrecorder)):

```
sudo apt install simplescreenrecorder
```