# Cannot open pdf files in mounted usb drive using Okular

Tags: usb-drive, okular

Whenever I try opening a PDF file in a mounted usb drive using Okular, it gives me this error: 
`Could not open file:///media/walkeknow/F8A2-34D9/example.pdf`

[image: Okular error dialog]

I have installed okular using `sudo snap install okular` because the `apt-get` method does not render the in-app icons for some reason on my system.

`which okular` command gives: `/snap/bin/okular`

The files open using Ubuntu's default Document Viewer evince. However I prefer using Okular. Is there any fix to this?

Comment: How did you installed Okular? Please add output of `which okular` to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get access to USB-storage from the application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap)

Comment: @N0rbert I tried the answer in the link you marked this question is a duplicate of, but `snap connect okular:removable-media` gave `error: snap "okular" has no plug named "removable-media"`

Comment: I see, so see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Snap problem

Okular does not support removable media while installed as Snap. You should remove it

```
snap remove okular
```

In other words it does not support `snap connect okular:removable-media` plug.

## Okular from APT (deb-package)

### Installation

Then install deb-packaged version instead with

```
sudo apt-get install okular
```

### Set-up look and feel

To get normal look and feel you need to install Breeze KDE theme with

```
sudo apt-get install breeze qt5ct
```

and select it from `qt5ct` with

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct qt5ct
```

then switch to *Icon Theme* tab and select *Breeze* here and hit *Save*:

[image: qt5ct]

To make changes permanent add this line to your `~/.profile` with

```
echo "export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct" >> ~/.profile
```

then reboot and use Okular with files from anywhere:

[image: Okular on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME]

Note: I tested the method above on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME Shell and MATE.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that with the deb installation using apt-get method, Okular does not render the in-app icons for some reason on my system. That is why I had to install it using snap

Comment: This is fixable. Are you using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I am using 18.04 LTS

Comment: @KewalShah See updated answer above. I have fixed look and feel problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto ubuntu's software manager.
2. Goto Installed.
3. Locate Okular and press it.
4. Change the permissions to "read/write files on removable device".