# Android Studio - apps not allowed permissions to save files, can't change either with Eiciel app

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-studio

I've tried what seems to be everything.  Changing permissions in the home folder to my user ownership.  Installing the manager Eiciel it won't let me change permissions on apps since everything belongs to root!

And I can't find a way to login to Ubuntu Studio as sudo or any other way to grant permissions.  How does one fix this issue?

I tried adding my username user to visudo from su.  After running a terminal and typing: sudo shutdown now, it seems to save files now and actually allows me to shutdown the system in Ubuntu Studio, but the permissions app Eiciel still won't allow me to add permissions to any apps.  Synaptic Package Manager won't let me select downloaded .deb files in my Download directory to install either (could be another problem IDK).  Geany located in /usr/bin/geany found with: locate -e geany from the root directory.  Tips?

UPDATE, NOT A GREAT (BUT WORKING) SOLUTION: I ran this (I'm sure it's not the proper way to give permissions) from a su terminal in the root directory; the program I want to give write access to is in usr/bin: chown -R usr user:user

Now Geany shows up with check boxes and I can edit permissions.  There has to be a better way to do this.  Doesn't seem like this is in line with how security should be setup.

https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups/

[image]

Comment: You don't want to change permissions of system files unless you really know what your doing or you want to trash the system. Could it be that Android Studio is installed as a snap and you need to configure it's permissions? Please take a look at the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap), probably that's helpful.

Comment: It looks very similar to the problems in that post, but I don't know how to apply it here rather than owning system files.  I do see Snap installed with Ubuntu Studio.  Suggestions?