# Musescore can't acces the /media folder

Tags: 18.04, permissions, musescore

I installed Musescore v 3.3.4. on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. When I try to open file from folder /media, I get message "Permission denied".

[image: Error Message]

I tried to connect removable media by this:

```
sudo snap connect musescore:removable-media
```

but I got this:

```
error: snap "musescore" has no plug named "removable-media"
```

[image: Snap connection]

Does anyone have any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

According to [snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management)

```
sudo snap connect musescore:removable-media :removable-media
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this doesn't work. There is still the same error: snap "musescore" has no plug named "removable-media"

Comment: Okay, I do not use snap https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap/1034065#1034065