# LibreOffice 6.3 Base Snap - Permissions

Tags: permissions, libreoffice, snap

> The lock file could not be opened for exclusive access by LibreOffice,
>   due to missing permission to create a lock file on that location or
>   lack of free disk space.

I haven't a lot of free space - 10GB but that should be enough to open a 2 row test file.

I was trying a simple test before recommending Base to an inexpert user, at the moment I can't do so, unless there is a very simple way to fix this. I've had this sort of thing happen with other Snaps, so I'm inclined to stick to debs where possible in future.

Comment: The libre office fresh ppa currently provides v6.3 via deb packages

Comment: Remember to report the problem to the Snap author with enough detail so that they can reproduce it. They cannot fix a problem that they are unaware of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get access to USB-storage from the application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap)

Comment: @N0rbert I'll recommend that page to the inexpert user I mentioned above.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Good thought, I tried that, I was a bit confused because there were 20 or so. It didn't install.

Comment: You just need to add the ppa and the update will show up in the update manager (if you already have an older version of libreoffice installed as deb.) Otherwise, you'll have to install with `sudo apt install libreoffice`

Answer (score 2):

I tried a sort of "Windows solution", but instead of switching off and on again, I un-installed and re-installed it, and the problem has gone! I'll still avoid Snaps wherever possible though..

Comment: Did you reinstall the snap or did you install the deb version?

Comment: I avoid snaps -- for a number of reasons. They are very convenient for distributors but they introduce complications for users and are architecturally ugly in the system context. I have sometimes resorted to building my own from source.

Comment: @Bruni I used Ubuntu "Software" which doesn't mention "From the Snap store", so I assume it's from a deb. It didn't show originally, then I uninstalled and re-installed LibreOffice and it showed, but had the above mentioned problem. I think I had downloaded a Snap as I couldn't find a deb. It's another problem with Snaps, that it's not made absolutely clear what you've got. Unless you can remember the commands to check which Debian and which Snaps you have installed. That means problems for novices and me who can't remember the commands.

Comment: @Bruni After I had installed the Snap the old menu items were still there plus the Snap versions! Another reason to avoid them - there doesn't seem to be adequate synchronisation between the two systems.