# How to access files outside of /home in snap apps?

Tags: permissions, snap

I have just upgraded to a recent version of Ubuntu that uses snap apps, and I have trouble understanding how I'm supposed to use them to work with files outside of `/home`. I have three disks in my machine, a large photo library on `sdb`, backup drives, and other things. As snap apps are confined, they cannot access any of them.

Only solution I can think of, is to bind mount everything to some folder under `/home`, but that seems like a terrible thing to do every single time I want to look at a file. Searching the web brings up blog posts about "snap interfaces" and "snap connections", but it is unclear to me if that could be helpful.

So the question is: **What is the intended method for using snap apps to work with files stored outside of `/home`?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get access to USB-storage from the application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap)

Comment: @N0rbert Answer given there does not tell us that connecting to `removable-media` gives app the rights for things under /mnt, so, no

Comment: TL;DR: You can't. The reason is pure stupidity and stubbornness from the app designers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> what is the intended method for using snap apps to work with files stored outside of /home?

The snap should be designed to do that under confinement by making use of the [`removable-media` interface](https://snapcraft.io/docs/removable-media-interface). Connecting such an interface will grant confined access to drives mounted in `/media` as well as `/mnt`.

To see if the snap in question supports this, run `snap connections <snap name>`. For example, for Nextcloud:

```
$ snap connections nextcloud
Interface        Plug                       Slot           Notes
network          nextcloud:network          :network       -
network-bind     nextcloud:network-bind     :network-bind  -
removable-media  nextcloud:removable-media  -              -
```

Since `nextcloud:removable-media` has no associated slot, that means the interface is not connect, thus Nextcloud cannot access removable media. To connect it, we can run `sudo snap connect nextcloud:removable-media`. Then the connections look like the following:

```
$ snap connections nextcloud
Interface        Plug                       Slot              Notes
network          nextcloud:network          :network          -
network-bind     nextcloud:network-bind     :network-bind     -
removable-media  nextcloud:removable-media  :removable-media  manual
```

Now that the plug is connected to a slot, Nextcloud now has confined access to removable media in `/media/` and `/mnt`. Other applications will work the same way if the developer built such functionality in. If they didn't, log a bug! You can find where to log a bug with `snap info <snap name>`, for example:

```
$ snap info nextcloud
<snip>
contact:   https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap
<snip>
```

Comment: Hi, that's a really good, thorough answer. I guess I got mislead into thinking that "removable media interface" is for just that, removable media like CDs or flash drives, because that's what it sounds like....