# Files from separate partition not accessible by Okular and GIMP (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, gimp, okular

During installation of Ubuntu 18.04 I created a separate partition `/store`. Files are accessible, but I cannot open files on it with okular and GIMP. No exact errors are displayed, okular just says `Could not open file:///store/1.pdf.`
GIMP says: `Opening '/store/2.jpg' failed:Could not open '/store/2.jpg' for reading: No such file or directory`

However other programs, such as chrome, document viewer, kolourpaint read pdf, jpg files perfectly.

When inside okular/GIMP I click file->open, /store is not displayed among other folders. Neither symbolic link to it, residing in ~/Desktop is displayed.

What can be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be the limitation of installing programs with snap: it makes only files from home folder accessible. So the solution is to remove okular and gimp from snap and install using apt:

```
# okular
sudo snap remove okular
sudo apt install okular

# gimp
sudo snap remove gimp
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp # without 2 previous lines gimp 2.8 will be installed
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the snap and reverting to the regular APT version, if available, indeed works around the permission limits of a Snap.

In case you do not have that alternative or prefer the snap version, you may want to check the permissions in Software. Opening the permission "Read/write files on removable storage" will grant the snap application access to media mounted under /media or /mnt. The snap package has to provide that interface for this to work. See [this Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228899/accessing-files-outside-of-home-in-snap-apps?rq=1) question and the [snap documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/removable-media-interface).