# pdftk works in home folder but not in www

Tags: 18.04, pdftk

I have installed `pdftk` using snap in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo snap install pdftk
```

In my home folder `pdftk` works fine:

```
root@localhost:/home# a.pdf output secure.128.pdf owner_pw 123456

root@localhost:/home# ls
a.pdf  secure.128.pdf
```

But in the `/var/www` folder it doesn't work:

```
root@localhost:/var/www/multi/pdfs# ls
a.pdf

root@localhost:/var/www/multi/pdfs# pdftk a.pdf output secure.128.pdf owner_pw 123456
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
a.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

Comment: Can you try absolute path (e.g. `/var/www/multi/pdf/a.pdf`) and see if it is working?

Comment: `pdftk /var/www/multi/pdfs/a.pdf output /var/www/multi/pdfs/secure.128.pdf owner_pw 123456` gives the same error

Comment: Likely related: [accessing files outside of /home in snap apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228899/accessing-files-outside-of-home-in-snap-apps)

Answer (score 0):

As [steeldriver commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375839/pdftk-wok-from-home-folder-but-not-in-www#comment2368989_1375839), this is probably related to `pdftk` being installed as a snap application. If you want, you may check [the post steeldriver linked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228899/accessing-files-outside-of-home-in-snap-apps) to see if the `pdftk` snap is built with support to access files outside `~`.

I suggest that you use the non-snap version of `pdftk`. Unfortunately, Ubuntu 18.04 does not include `pdftk` in its default repositories (thankfully, 20.04 has it), so it has to be built from source. I'm quoting the relevant part of [David Foerster's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028983/618353) for how to build it:

> 1. Install the build tools and dependencies:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install git default-jdk-headless ant \
>        libcommons-lang3-java libbcprov-java
>    ```
>
>    Of course you can use a different supported JDK than the one supplied by `default-jdk-headless`.
> 2. Download [Marc Vinyal’s pdftk fork](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk):
>
>    ```
>    git clone https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk.git
>    cd pdftk
>    ```
> 3. Place symbolic links to the required libraries into the `lib` folder:
>
>    ```
>    mkdir lib
>    ln -st lib /usr/share/java/{commons-lang3,bcprov}.jar
>    ```
> 4. Build the JAR package:
>
>    ```
>    ant jar
>    ```
> 5. Run the JAR package:
>
>    ```
>    java -jar build/jar/pdftk.jar --help
>    ```
> 6. (Optional) To run the JAR package, e. g. when you distribute it to other systems, you need at least a working (headless) JRE like from
>    the `default-jre-headless` package as well as the Java libraries
>    `libcommons-lang3-java` and `libbcprov-java`:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install default-jre-headless libcommons-lang3-java libbcprov-java
>    ```
>
>    Again you can use a different JRE than `default-jre-headless`. This pdftk fork also supports builds for older JRE versions (≥ 7
>    according to the documentation).
> 7. (Optional) You can teach Linux to execute JAR (Java Archive) files via
>    [`update-binfmts(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/update-binfmts.8.html).
>    Most JREs shipped in Deb packages, including those in Canonical’s
>    package repositories, take care of that during installation, though it
>    appears to be buggy in some OpenJDK packages.