# Not able to import photos into digiKam from second hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, digikam

I have two drives on my desktop. One 1tb drive where I have my programs installed (including digiKam) and a larger secondary drive where I store photos etc.

I'm trying to import my photos from the secondary hard drive into digiKam but when I click import -> add images this drive does not show up an option to import from.

Does anyone know how I can import from my secondary hard drive into digiKam?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and digiKam 7.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have the snap version of digiKam, and it probably hasn't been given permission to the drive. I believe the official documentation is [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management).

But since you're specifically looking to access a folder, the answer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228899/accessing-files-outside-of-home-in-snap-apps) might be more on-target.

I finally found the GUI way to do it buried in another question, if this will help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1158109/1379110

Comment: I tried this but no luck unfortunately. The same technique worked with shotwell which is currently importing my files, so maybe its an issue with digikam. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, it is NOT a snap issue (for once), but I wanted to use an SSH/SFTP mount. I could see the folder but it would be empty in digiKam, not in the file browser.

APT version had the same issue, left menu empty.

---

```
sudo apt install sshfs
mkdir ~/media
sshfs patrick@192.168.178.8:/media/pool/media /home/patrick/media
```

I downloaded the appImage from the site directly, which did show me the folder contents. Sadly the drives didn't show up in the left menu but I could browse to it via `/media/patrick/DRIVE_NAME`