# Can't download files after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: downloads, 21.10, browser, 22.04

Everything was fine until I upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04. Now, whenever I try to download something in any browser (Brave, Vivaldi, Firefox, etc), I can only download it to my home folder or any folder inside the system drive (I use a separate SSD for Ubuntu). I use my data HDD on auto-mount so i'ts always mounted & I have no problem reading/writing from it (I can open Rhythmbox and play music from there, wget files into it via Terminal, copy, paste & delete), but I can't 'Save As' on my browsers, it asks me if I want to save but files won't download, show up in the HDD or even in the browsers download list. Already checked permissions & apps have permission. Does anybody know how to solve this or even what's causing it?

Comment: Does `wget` work? Like, take a file you want to download, even a PDF or something, `cd` to a non-working location, and try to download it with wget. Also remember to put a single quote at the beginning and end of the URL

Comment: are your browsers installed with snap or apt? If snap, do they have access to your media outside your home - check the interfaces? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228899/how-to-access-files-outside-of-home-in-snap-apps

Comment: @cocomac Yes, wget works everywhere, with everything (images, videos, pdfs, etc)

Comment: @kurja I have both. Brave and Firefox are snaps while Vivaldi and Chrome are both apt. Same behavior on all of them ;-;
[UPDATE] just checked the interfaces, no problem there :/

Comment: Try installing firefox as a .deb, and report if the issue still persists. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using deb packaged firefox and chrome and I could not save files outside of the home directories.

My problem is with bookmarks on the gnome Files app. I removed all of the bookmarks and added them again. I can then save files to the bookmarked locations.

Comment: Thanks! I had some bookmarks so I did this and it worked!

Comment: Unfortunately, deleting and re-adding my bookmarks in Nautilus did not resolve the problem here.  I just upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04, and now Chrome (deb), Thunderbird (snap), and FireFox (snap) will not open nor save to any network drives (a home Ubuntu server); all of these apps read/saved to the same server before the upgrade this afternoon.

Comment: @asavage I haven't tried network disks yet, only local downloads. Will test it and comment again here

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1767316

Comment: i don't even get a *prompt* asking me where I want to save anything, the browser just *hangs*

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for quite some time and it turned out to be the apparmor service. Running `systemctl stop apparmor` fixed the problem temporarily. You might want to run `systemctl disable apparmor` for the setting to persist across reboots.

Note that AppArmor is a Mandatory Access Control (MAC) system which is a kernel (LSM) enhancement to confine programs to a limited set of resources. If one has security concerns, turning off this service may not be the best solution.

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, 22.04 here.. but now i'm using "**Chromium**" temporarily. It works fine! Check it out.

Comment: I have the same problem and I noticed that several "questions" have been written on this. Some have said it is an intentional change related to security. For now, I've resigned myself to saving to some location under my home directory and then manually moving the file afterwards.