# How to sort out permission problem on mounted partitions?

Tags: permissions

I have just installed a citation manager Zotero using `snap`. I added one of AddOns called Zotfile to locally manage PDFs instead of storing them on a cloud. I configured Ubuntu such that my Documents are on mounted partition. I also use LVM.

Within Zotero, when I try to configure the AddOn Zotfile and point at one of the folders on a mounted partition, I get permission error. When I use any local folder on the same partition, everything's OK. How can I solve the problem? I am confused because Zotero is installed by root and has root:root permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get access to USB-storage from the application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap) - the `snap connect zotero-snap:removable-media` will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. It did help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I have one more question. Zotero is a PDF manager. I realised I cannot attach PDFs to references. Does it need another interface connection enabled? I am so confused about all that snap applications :/

Comment: I'm not really sure. I do not use Snap'ed version of Zotero. On ordinary version I use "Attach Stored Copy of File…" without problems.

Comment: It’s working now. I had to reinstall Zotero and also remove then add a group which I wanted to import papers to.