# Zotero reference manager installed from snap cannot process files via Firefox connector

Tags: permissions, snap

I have a Zotero application, a PDF manager, installed via snap. I used to have a problem with accessing removable media but it's been sorted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap).

There is another issue. Zotero should accept files from websites, which are sent via Firefox connector. The files should be automatically attached but it doesn't work. It also does not let me attach files stored locally. Actually, it doesn't let me even use this functionality in the application. This option is greyed out. I was wondering if this could also be related to another interface connection that needs to be enabled in order for an application to handle files in the system. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may not be a specific interface to handle this communication with your browser. As a workaround, install the snap without confinement, i.e. in classic mode. For this, you need to remove the current installation and reinstall it with the --classic option:

```
sudo snap remove zotero-snap
sudo snap install zotero-snap --classic
```