# Telegram cannot access my HD partition

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, telegram

Hope everyone is doing OK. Since I upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 20.04, I cannot access my HD partition to send files via Telegram. Every time I want to attach a file/pic, I need to copy it to the "Documents" in Home. As you can imagine, it's not practical at all, so I'd be great if someone knew how to solve it.

TIA and keep safe!

Comment: Is it installed from a snap or via apt?

Comment: I installed Telegram via snap.  I have the same limitation.

Comment: Please check this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap