# Permit an application to access other drives

Tags: snap, clementine, restricted-access

What would be the command to allow a specific application to view other drives, like Clementine ?

I can't add content to my library from other drives.

Ubuntu 20.10 groovy (x86-64)

With Cinnamon 4.6.7

kernel: 5.8.0-43-generic

Comment: I have my music stored on an internal drive in my PC which is mounted at boot time. Clementine can access the drive quite straightforwardly. What specific problem are you encountering?

Comment: /media : Permission denied

Comment: It would have to be more than just /media but point to the mounted drive such as /media/graham/STORAGE/Music as in my case... /media/graham/STORAGE is the mount point, and music the directory where the files are stored on the mounted drive. /media on its own won't achieve much

Comment: The mountpoint is: '/mnt/ca90892c-2780-4e09-bd51-289244ad86c6/Musique' Here is a link to a screenshot: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xl1WIdL_CFUDAqfjhrA1NIrUUTeX_Yd7/view?usp=sharing) (It's the same for media and mnt)

Comment: Did you install Clementine as a snap version?  Might be able to adjust permissions in software store, or install the .deb version.

Comment: I can't access the other store from within Cinnamon. I had to download the deb package to intsall this version without loging of. It seems The only store available in Cinnamon environement is Snap. Thanks !

Comment: Snaps are known to have trouble using other drives.  Should be able to tell snap from deb in store.

Comment: I donwloaded here: [link](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/groovy/universe/base/clementine)
I have both now and the deb one works fine ! [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jykUjGFf-G0sVKOvRvTUCY_ASSG37LIR/view?usp=sharing)
I'll uninstall the Snaps version

Comment: indeed, I can also see the other version in the Snap store, but know I also see the other icon, what wasn't the case in Gnome env. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LYWBoXen99L9mVphBwjFTgbB6TQAuAYf/view?usp=sharing) The Snap version has been uninstalled - Thanks again ! Cheers !

Comment: Snaps are *deliberately prohibited* from looking outside your /home directory. That can be changed...if the snap packager opened that capability. If not, nothing you can do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get access to USB-storage from an application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-an-application-installed-as-snap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've entered a terminal as root** `sudo su` then:

**1. Purge [the snap version](https://snapcraft.io/install/clementine/ubuntu) installed of the clementine package**:

```
snap remove clementine --purge
```

**2.   Use `apt install` instead :**

```
apt install clementine
```

I've also seen this issue in other/later Ubuntu Flavors's releases using gnome-software as a base like it seems to me, that installing another one (like synaptic or snaps) could cause this. Maybe there's a general way to do so that the rights of installed package are set too for a freshly installed software manager.

By the way, I always use an Ubuntu flavors's releases as a base installation and never have trouble with gnome-software installed packages (mostly apt install with terminal). I did not use Snaps on my other tests.

- [See here for package details.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clementine)
- [See here for the information about the use of snap](https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started)

After that Clementine could access all my disks like it should.

Comment: As a solution this might work too, though I haven't tested it yet because I replaced all my snap installs by apt. I'll try it if I need a new installation. - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-an-application-installed-as-snap

Answer (score 0):

Just give the required permission

```
sudo snap connect clementine:removable-media
sudo snap connect clementine:desktop-legacy
```