# Unable to open file attachment in note taking app Joplin, getting error access denied

Tags: 20.04, permissions, snap, attachment

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed Joplin using Snapcraft by the following command in terminal -

```
sudo snap install joplin-james-carroll
```

I have a file DMBS.odg. I have attached the file in my Joplin App notebook. After that, when I click on the attachment I am unable to open the file. I am getting Access Denied error.

Following is my error -

```
Access to /home/payel/snap/joplin-james-carroll/56/.config/joplin-desktop/tmp/edited_resources/DBMS(1).org was denied.
```

Also, my file name is DBMS.org and not DBMS(1).org. But in the error message it is saying DBMS(1).org

**Note:**

I have installed Joplin in both my Ubuntu desktop and Android mobile and I have synchronized my Joplin App in both devices using Dropbox. The attachment is opening without any problem in my Android device. It is not opening only in my Desktop device.

**Update:**

```
snap connect joplin-desktop:removable-media
```

Gives me the output -

```
error: snap "joplin-desktop" has no plug named "removable-media"
```

---

```
snap interfaces  | grep -v ".*-$" | grep joplin
```

Gives me the output -

```
gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004        joplin-james-carroll
gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes         chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,libreoffice,mysql-workbench-community,opera,skype,snap-store
gtk-common-themes:icon-themes          chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,leafpad,libreoffice,mysql-workbench-community,opera,skype,snap-store
gtk-common-themes:sound-themes         chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,libreoffice,mysql-workbench-community,opera,skype,snap-store
:audio-playback                        chromium,joplin-james-carroll,libreoffice,opera,skype,vlc
:browser-support                       chromium:browser-sandbox,discord,joplin-james-carroll,opera:browser-sandbox,skype:browser-sandbox,skype,spotify
:desktop                               chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,leafpad,libreoffice,mysql-workbench-community,opera,skype,snap-store,spotify,vlc
:desktop-legacy                        chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,leafpad,libreoffice,mysql-workbench-community,opera,skype,snap-store,vlc
:gsettings                             chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,leafpad,libreoffice,mysql-workbench-community,opera,skype,snap-store,spotify
:home                                  chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,leafpad,libreoffice,mysql-workbench-community,opera,skype,spotify,vlc
:network                               chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,leafpad,libreoffice,mysql-workbench-community,opera,skype,snap-store,spotify,vlc
:opengl                                chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,libreoffice,mysql-workbench-community,opera,skype,snap-store,spotify,vlc
:unity7                                chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,libreoffice,opera,skype,spotify,vlc
:wayland                               chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,libreoffice,mysql-workbench-community,opera,skype,snap-store,spotify
:x11                                   chromium,discord,joplin-james-carroll,leafpad,libreoffice,mysql-workbench-community,opera,skype,snap-store,spotify,vlc

'snap interfaces' is deprecated; use 'snap connections'.
-                                      joplin-james-carroll:avahi-control
-                                      joplin-james-carroll:cups-control
-                                      joplin-james-carroll:password-manager-service
-                                      joplin-james-carroll:pulseaudio
-                                      joplin-james-carroll:removable-media
```

**Update 2:**

Followed the steps as asked by @N0bert

Now getting the error -

```
Access to /home/payel/snap/joplin-desktop/4/.config/joplin-desktop/tmp/edited-resources/DBMS.odg was denied
```

Only in the original error `joplin-james-carroll` is now replaced by `joplin-desktop`

Comment: You can try to run `snap connect joplin-desktop:removable-media`. It may be some kind of [this similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/1034030/66509). Also add output of `snap interfaces  | grep -v ".*-$" | grep joplin` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert updated the question

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems that you use wrong version of Joplin. The `joplin-james-carroll` is unofficial, but `joplin-desktop` is official.

So you have to:

1. Remove unofficial snap:

   ```
   sudo snap remove joplin-james-carroll
   ```
2. Install official snap:

   ```
   sudo snap install joplin-desktop
   ```
3. Connect removable media to freshly installed snap:

   ```
   sudo snap connect joplin-desktop:removable-media
   ```

Comment: still getting the same error - `Access to /home/payel/snap/joplin-desktop/4/.config/joplin-desktop/tmp/edited-resources/DBMS.odg was denied`