# Microsoft Teams: Could not read the contents of FOLDER?

Tags: 20.04, permissions, mount, snap, microsoft-teams

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I've installed Microsoft Teams using Ubuntu Software.

When I want to upload a new file to Microsoft teams that is on a different SSD I get the following error:

```
Could not read the contents of backup
Error opening dictionary '/mnt/backup': Permission denied
```

[image: Error Image]

I've mounted the drive using the following line in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6fa6ae01-fcd4-4771-a89d-cffa9744d630 /mnt/backup auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

When using Firefox it can upload files from the mounted drive without any problems.

Has anyone any idea how to fix this?

### Edit:

Tried the `snap connect some-snap-name:removable-media` command:

> error: snap "teams-for-linux" has no plug named "removable-media"

### Edit 2:

Also tried ["Microsoft Teams - Preview"](https://snapcraft.io/teams). Unfortunately the same problem.

> error: snap "teams" has no plug named "removable-media"

### Edit 3:

Also tried "Microsoft Teams - Insiders". Unfortunately the same problem.

> error: snap "teams-insiders" has no plug named "removable-media"

Comment: Is it a Snap package?

Comment: Yes, I installed Microsoft Teams using the Ubuntu Software Application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get access to USB-storage from an application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-an-application-installed-as-snap)

Comment: Thanks that helps, but unfortunately I the error I posted in the question.

Comment: I will open a GitHub Issue on Teams.

Comment: Opening issue on https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux is good  idea. Then I would recommend other snaps with teams - https://snapcraft.io/teams or https://snapcraft.io/teams-insiders .

Comment: I tried both versions, but unfortunately I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the search on [Repology](https://repology.org/project/teams/versions) and then in [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/plain/PKGBUILD?h=teams) - MS has deb-package of the Teams application.

So you have to remove Snap based version and then install deb-version with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/pool/main/t/teams/teams_1.4.00.13653_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./teams_1.4.00.13653_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked.