# Giving Microsoft Teams access to my external hard drive

Tags: permissions, external-hdd, microsoft-teams

I have an external hard drive, and I am using Microsoft Teams. But this application is not granted permission to access files on that external hard drive. How can I change that?

EDIT: I have given it ALL permissions in the Ubuntu Software app. I am using the electron-based Linux app.

Comment: Have you installed the snap version? If so you need to give it additional permissions indeed.

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-an-application-installed-as-snap) for giving permission to snap apps.

Comment: Can you mount the hard drive in a directory the `snap` can access? E.g. `/home/$USER/mnt/myDisk`?

Comment: If you installed Teams via the `.deb` package from Microsoft's site, then you may need to create an AppArmor profile and grant Teams access to the external devices that way. Usually this isn't required, though ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Teams: Could not read the contents of FOLDER?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334699/microsoft-teams-could-not-read-the-contents-of-folder)