# Access removable media with snaps

Tags: permissions, external-hdd, restricted-access

My second SSD is mounted at "/home/maxime/Data/" to facilitate remote access. Also, since there is not a lot a space in my system SSD, I moved the /tmp folder to "/home/maxime/Data/.tmp"
My problem is that now many applications simply do not launch because they don't have access to the external SSD.
I tried the `sudo snap connect` commands, :

```
maxime@maxime:~$ sudo snap connect google-chrome-stable:removable-media
error: snap "google-chrome-stable" has no plug named "removable-media"
```

I think this command gives access to /media and /mnt, but my drive isn't mounted there. Also, many apps do not have "plugs" to connect to an external SSD because they don't see a use for it. BUT, since my tmp folder is on an external SSD, I would like for all apps to have access to this drive.

Comment: Is your `google-chrome` a snap?   I've only see *deb* packages for chrome.. We don't know your release details, and it may help if you tell us how you've referred or mounted your `tmp` (I assume an `fstab` entry, but providing that entry may help us understand your issue).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get access to USB-storage from an application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-an-application-installed-as-snap). Use official chrome deb-package instead.

Comment: So my drive is mounted as follow:
`/dev/disk/by-uuid/026E62771A0969F0 /home/maxime/Data auto uid=1000,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0`

I am not 100% sure that chrome is a snap, but since software install also doesn't lauch, I assume the problem was the same.
There are other app, like firefox, that have no problem launching