# Accessing NTFS Drive from 3rd Party Application

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I have tried to use P3X OneNote under Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS but I have encountered the problem, that from the application (insert file) I cannot access my NTFS drive with the message /media/peter/Data Permission denied. If I try to open the drive from Files, it works without any problems. I encounter the same behaviour when I try to insert a file in Joplin as well. /media/peter/Data is set to attributes drwxrwxrwx. Thank you for any suggestions I could try!

Comment: Most common problem is that Windows fast start up sets hibernation flag, preventing read/write using Linux NTFS driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Could also be that NTFS needs  chkdsk or other repairs which only can be done from Windows.

Comment: Need more info on permissions? Not just the attributes 'rwx'. `ls -al /media/peter/Data`. Also is Data  folder automatically mounted at boot-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Apart from the system partitions, an internal partition, i.e., a partition on a disk in the computer, is not mounted by default. To use such partition, it must first be mounted explicitly by clicking its icon in Files.
- Even then, sandboxed applications may not be able to access the partition. Your applications likely are installed as snap packages. This is a new packaging format that "sandboxes" the applications: applications cannot anymore access any resource on your computer. Likely, both of your applications have been granted access to your home folder, but not to removable drives.

Either copy the files you want to work with to somewhere under your home folder for editing, or grant your applications permission to access removable drives, which are mounted under /media/. This can be done from within the Snap store.

Comment: Hi, thanks, you were right about the sandboxed applications. The problem is, that neither OneNote, nor Joplin has the possibilty by default to access removable media. So I found the guide to add it (at least for Joplin, not for OneNote) here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-an-application-installed-as-snap

Comment: Indeed, a snap must be shipped with the "interface" for removable drive access.