# Open/Edit documents using Onlyoffice in the non-installation drive

Tags: permissions, mount, sshfs

I have an installation of onlyoffice-desktopeditors with the following specifications

OS version: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
App version: 6.4.2
Downloaded from: Installed trough snapd

Everything works great, however, the app does not let me open/edit any document that is not on the home drive were the software is installed.
In particular, I have a physical data drive on the machine and if I try to access it trough onlyoffice it says: Could not read : permission denied.
Furthermore, if i try to access folders that I have mounted trough sshfs they will not even appear in the onlyoffice file browser.
I have another Ubuntu machine with a similar installation and the same problems arise.

Do anyone knows how to edit documents outside installation drive in onlyoffice?

Comment: I usually install onlyoffice-desktops like this (apt-get install --install-recommends onlyoffice-desktopeditors): https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/installation/desktop-install-ubuntu.aspx. For questions about errors and functionality, go here: https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DesktopEditors#user-feedback-and-support

Comment: @JohanPalych indeed installing trough apt solved the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get access to USB-storage from an application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-an-application-installed-as-snap)