# 22.04 Installation Hung at Firefox snap

Tags: system-installation, firefox, 22.04

Upgrading 20.04 to 22.04 on an ASUS laptop, installation has been hung at "installing Firefox snap" for 24 hours. System is still responsive, did not lock (unlike other questions), but the terminal log has not changed in 24 hours.

1. How much longer should I give it before killing the install?
2. What's the likely outcomes after killing the install? Will I be able to use whatever of 22.04 loaded or have to go back to an ISO?

Comment: 1) You should not wait longer 2) difficult for most of us to predict. Be indeed ready for the possibility to have to do a new install from installation medium

Comment: Check for a child window that popped up asking for some permission. That's what happened on my end.

Comment: Same thing just happened to me... A "configuring Firefox" dialog box came up during the install, but the "next" button didn't actually work, so I crashed the window. About five minutes later the upgrade suddenly continued again.

Comment: I also had the same. But I think it was because my home drive is a mounted drive. Snap apps do not work for us in our office!

Comment: [How to get access to USB-storage from an application installed as a snap?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1034030/)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue(I had Firefox running during the install, my bad!).

Here's what I've done to solve this.

1. Stop the upgrade process. (Since I was in terminal, I used ctrl+c).
2. 

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

3. 

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

And it works like a charm.

Comment: Accidentally left FireFox running when I kicked off the 22.04.01 upgrade, and hit this same problem.  This fix worked for me.

Comment: I simply shut down Firefox, and about 3 mins later, after clicking cancel/resume a few times, it just resumed.

Comment: I manually opened Firefox (It wasn't on), then closed it, and the installation immediately unfroze. (Thanks, @RowanGontier!)