# Latest Ubuntu update failed, VM refuses to boot

Tags: package-management, kernel

Earlier today, I started my Ubuntu VM and a dialogue box asked me if I wanted to update to the latest Ubuntu upgrade package. I clicked OK, but the installation hanged at Firefox Snap. Another dialogue box prompted me to close all my Firefox windows before continuing with the install, but it wouldn't let me click Next even though I had no Firefox window opened. The Ubuntu upgrade was the first thing I did booting up.

My issue looked like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404419/22-04-installation-hung-at-firefox-snap), so I killed the install as well, and unfortunately, his fix didn't work for me. I still could reboot Ubuntu, and I then launched the Package Manager and attempted to fix my broken package install. I thought I succeeded at first, but upon rebooting Ubuntu again, I get this screen, and then nothing. [Boot-up screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iw6h.png)

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Linux/Ubuntu.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix my problem?

Comment: Ah, you're right, I should have written it up. If I remember correctly, it couldn't get permission, and the terminal asked me if I was root.

Comment: @nmath The reboot sequence hangs on that screen, and I apparently can't enter anything.

Comment: I see. Can you reboot into recovery? From there you can drop to a root shell prompt and enable networking which will allow you to run commands and make changes to the file system.

Comment: @nmath Thank you, I fixed my issue! I managed to reboot into recovery, as you said, and this time the commands given in the answer in my link worked. I assume I must have mistyped them the first time around. Thanks again for your help!