# Upgrade to 22.04 fails at Restart Computer; unable to restart computer

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 22.04, shutdown

Today attempted to upgrade from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS.  Encountered some problems during upgrade, but those appeared to have resolved themselves (see below).  Once I hit the "Restart Computer" button, however, the GUI disappeared and was replaced with a full, blank screen with an error message starting:

```
/shutdown: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-249.so: camo
open shared object file: No such file or directory
[144120.321497] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!  exitcode=0x00007f00
```

The screen is unresponsive to mouse or keyboard input.  I attempted to power-down the machine and restart but the power key is not responding.  (This is a Lenovo Thinkpad where Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was factory-installed.)

**I am currently unable to turn the computer off.**

(During the installation, a prompt came up indicating that Firefox was to be installed via 'snap'.  I hit the "Next" button to allow the upgrade to proceed, but encountered problems similar to that described in [22.04 Installation Hung at Firefox snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404419/22-04-installation-hung-at-firefox-snap).  I hit Ctrl-C a couple of times, but eventually the upgrade process resumed and continued to the point of "Restart Computer.")

Suggestions as to how to proceed?  Thanks.

Comment: Well, immediately after posting, I tried again to turn the computer off.  This time I pushed down on the power button for about 20 seconds -- and the machine turned off.  I powered back on and the system appeared to properly log in to 22.04 LTS.  This was frightening!

Comment: i have the same error, any idea?