# Unable to login, blank screen does not revive, after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: login, login-screen, username, xscreensaver

Yesterday I attempted an OS upgrade from Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS.  The machine being upgraded was a new Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 10.  Following the upgrade I have two severe problems that render the machine unusable:

1. **When the screen goes blank, neither touching a key or moving the mouse brings the screen back to life.** The machine only responds to my holding down the power key for more than 8 seconds until the power button life goes out, then rebooting.
2. **Unable to log in.**  Once I power up, the login screen displays my name but also displays the phrase "Not listed?" underneath the box displaying my full name.  When I click on my full name, the Password box comes up, but when I enter my Password, the whole screen briefly flashes and returns me to the previous state, *i.e.,* displaying my full name and the words "Not listed?".  After a few minutes, the screen goes blank and I'm back to Problem 1.

**How Did I Get to This Point?**

This machine only arrived seven days ago and I did not begin setup until three days ago.  My previous machine (from a now defunct assembler) started with Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS and I've upgraded it over the years to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, including going from 20.04 to 22.04 last October.  Lenovo does not offer this model with 22.04 factory-installed, so once I had performed the initial setup I wanted to upgrade to 22.04 before transferring a lot of data from the old machine to the new.

The OS upgrade had some scary moments (see [Upgrade to 22.04 fails at Restart Computer; unable to restart computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461277/upgrade-to-22-04-fails-at-restart-computer-unable-to-restart-computer)), but I thought they had been overcome.  I was able to log on to log in, open a terminal, perform actions such as `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.  Via a USB stick I was able to import my `.bashrc` and similar files from the old machine and get them working.  Via USB stick I was also able to import my SSH keys into `~/.ssh` and verify that I could SSH-out from the machine.  Rerunning Software Update one more time, I was prompted to update one piece of software from Lenovo (as distinct from Canonical/Ubuntu).  I did so, though unfortunately I didn't write down the name of that software.

It was at about this time that I began to notice problems like #1 above.  I had been using Xscreensaver (which I've used for years on my older machine), but when I would click on the screen it would take multiple clicks to bring up the Xscreensaver's password prompt.  I would enter my password and get my desktop back, but Xscreensaver would indicate that it had crashed and asked if I wanted to send a crash report.  I could then use the machine for a while, and I experimented with disabling Xscreensaver, but when I would walk away and come back to a blank screen, they keyboard and mouse would be unresponsive and I would arrive at problem #1 above.

At some point I decided to try logging off when leaving the machine (rather than allowing the screen to go blank and lock on its own), but once I did that I became stuck in problem #2 above.

**What I Have Attempted So Far**

On bootup, Lenovo indicates that you can get to the "Start Interrupt Menu" by hitting Enter.  I have done so.  From there I selected to restore default configuration and Restart -- but that doesn't fix either problem #1 or #2 above.  My user is still "not listed" and when the screen goes blank it ceases to respond to keyboard or mouse input.

Suggestions?

Comment: The way you describe the issue minus all the unnecessary back story leaves me to suggest just do a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I would also suggest a fresh install of 22.04, particularly since most times the stock Ubuntu versions work better than the vendor specific ones (this observation is based on my experience with Dell and not lenovo though)

Comment: Given that I cannot even login on the ThinkPad, how would I do a fresh install of 22.04? (I probably have not done a fresh install on a PC since 2006.)

Comment: You make a boot USB with a fresh download of Ubuntu and follow a tutorial and install. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: I ultimately did to a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS by downloading an ISO from Ubuntu, loading it on to a USB drive, and booting the machine from that stick.  It went more smoothly than I anticipated.