# How to set download directory for Opera using Terminal in Ubuntu. Opera settings offer to select a directory navigating, but then changes it

Tags: command-line, directory, downloads, settings, opera

How to set the download directory for Opera using Terminal in Ubuntu. Inside Opera, in settings, a directory can be selected navigating, but Opera changes it instantly for another path/directory. Later, downloaded files are NOT found in the directory that user selected. And no where to be found, as if never has been downloaded. Means a lot of wasting time, and next resort will be to uninstall Opera right away.
Unless I can fix this annoying problem.

Comment: This is an XY problem. You need to understand that snaps run confined by default (Opera is a snap now) therefore they have access to $HOME only and by enabling additional permissions also /media and /mnt.

Comment: Did you check your extra permissions? What are they set to? What directory are you trying to save to and is this drive your main storage device? Also, you may want to review some of [these answers to this similar question about snap storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-an-application-installed-as-snap). Please let us know if these answers don't apply to your question so I can retract the close vote. It may help to also search for the same question related to Firefox as Firefox is also a Snap and follows a similar permission scheme.

Comment: Also, how did you install Opera? It seems that there is a deb version available from Opera. Did you install from the Snap store or from the Ubuntu Software app? Typically, it's best to only install from the Ubuntu Software app but if there is an application that installs a Snap that doesn't perform correctly, installing a deb downloaded from the source like Opera or Google chrome directly from Google may be your best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Snap version of Opera, you can install the deb version by downloading the deb file from Opera or by manually adding the Opera repository.

I recommend uninstalling the Snap version of Opera before you begin. Backup any personal data or take note of any settings as the will not transfer to the deb version of Opera.

**Method 1:**

First, download the deb file directly from Opera by clicking the download button on [the Opera webpage](https://www.opera.com/browsers/opera).

You will then need to copy that deb file to your user's `~/Downloads` directory (the downloads directory in your file browser [like Nautilus] and not the downloads directory for your web browser if you are using a snap).

Once the file is copied to your user's `~/Downloads` directory. Run the following command to install the file.

```
sudo apt install ~/Downloads/opera*.deb
```

Installing this deb file should automatically install the Opera repository and the stable branch of Opera.

**Method 2:**

Alternatively, you can manually install the Opera repository and then install the deb version using `apt`.

First, run the following command to add the key needed to verify the repository:

```
wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then, run the following command to add the repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list'
```

Finally, run the following commands to install opera-stable:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install opera-stable
```

According to [this Packages file](https://deb.opera.com/opera/dists/stable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages), there should be no snap dependencies.

Comment: I will follow your recommendation using method 2.

Comment: Just to clarify the problem I had:  Happened using Opera Version 91.0.4516.77, up to date, Update stream: Stable, System: Ubuntu Core 18 (x86_64; Ubuntu: GNOME).

Comment: All right! Did what you said and the problem was solved. Thank you!

Comment: @ArmandoRubke Yes, I believe Ubuntu core runs mostly snap packages by default. FYI, you will probably have to run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade` every once and a while like once per day or week to keep Opera up to date.