# Permission denied when trying to access external harddrive in OpenComic

Tags: permissions, external-hdd

I have an external usb harddrive, which I usually use on a windows pc. It has NTFS.  When I connect it with my ubuntu pc, it works immediately. I can access it in terminal and in nautilus. But when I try to open a file/folder from the app OpenComic, I get permission denied as shown in the screenshot. Help appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is OpenComic a snap app? Or installed via apt/repository. ?

Comment: I installed it via snap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1034030/906933).

The solution is that snap app needs to have the **removable-media** plug enabled in order to access USB storage and other drives.