# Grant Steam Snap access to second Hard Drive

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, steam

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 and it is fresh install. I have a 128GB SSD in which Steam is installed. However, I want to use my secondary Hard Drive 1TB for downloading all my games. I don't see any option to choose the secondary hard drive using Snap version. It was easy to find it in deb version. I checked Apps setting for additional permissions. However, I could not find permission to access secondary hard drive there. Apparently, read/write files on removable storage devices is present for other apps. Please help my Steam snap access the secondary hard drive and use it for downloading and playing games etc.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1034065/1691066

Comment: Removable media is enabled for Steam even after checking it through this method but still Steam does not allow me to select second hard drive for downloads.